# How to sync back Lyrics of music to iTunes?

Tags: sync, music, itunes

My setups:

- I use [iSyncr for PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.iSyncr) to sync my Android devices with iTunes.
- I use [PlayerPro Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro) which hooks with iSyncr's system.

Ratings and Play Counts are synced with iTunes both ways, but that's not true for Lyrics of music. If I add Lyrics in iTunes (Right Click ~> Get Info ~> Lyrics (tab)), I can see it in PlayerPro on Android. But, when I download lyrics using PlayerPro (Long Tap ~> View Lyrics), I fail to find it in iTunes after sync.

I have searched filesystems of Android devices to find any file, database containing Lyrics, but it seems that PlayerPro saves it in ID3 tag of music files. So, I don't see where's the problem. I have got the feeling that iSyncr doesn't sync back for such things, but I am not sure.

How to sync Lyrics from Android to iTunes on PC?
I can use alternatives for lyrics sync & lyrics download as long as I can view lyrics in PlayerPro & other syncs work as before.

**Update:**
PlayerPro support has confirmed that lyrics is saved inside music file. In case something goes wrong, it is saved in .lyr file in the directory of music.